# How can I figure out what is the name of this math font?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I would like to know the name of this math font. I do not how can I find it elsewhere and I think that the only place where people can help me is here.

The math font is illustrated in the following picture.

[image]

Comment: If this is duplicate, what is the name of the font then?

Comment: If you have a pdf version of this file, most viewers will tell you the fonts used in the document (File -> Properties). *A priori*, I'd say it's `Minion Pro`, which comes with Adobe Reader and has been adapted to type maths with LaTeX.